# Why won't my two divs expand the whole height of the containing div?

Tags: css

**HTML:**

```
            <div id="main" class="rounded-corners">

                <div id="benefits">

                    <img src="/benefits-heading.png" style="padding: 30px;" />

                    <div id="corporateside">
                        <h1>Corporate Benefits</h1>    
                        <p>blah</p>
                    </div>

                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

                    <div id="employeeside">
                        <h1>Employee Benefits</h1>
                        <p>blah</p>
                    </div>

                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#corporateside { width: 420px; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; padding: 20px; height: 100%; display: block;  }
#corporateside h1 { font-size: 24px; font-weight: 500; }
#corporateside h2 { color: #cc0000; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; padding-top: 10px; }
#corporateside p { padding: 0px; margin-top: -10px; }
#employeeside { width: 420px; position: absolute; right: 0; padding: 20px; height: 100%; display: block;  }
#employeeside h1 { font-size: 24px; font-weight: 500; }
#employeeside h2 { color: #cc0000; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; padding-top: 10px; }
#employeeside p { padding: 0px; margin-top: -10px; }
#benefits { position: relative; height: auto; }
#main { width: 940px; height: auto; background-color: #ffffff; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; background: #ffffff; border: 2px solid #ffc40d; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; -khtml-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px; }
```

I have fixed this issue by removing the `position: absolute;` from each div. Also I removed the `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` between the two divs. Thanks for your help!

Comment: coz they are position:absolute so why should they expand? please minify your problem and/or create jsfiddle for it.

Comment: @Trey Copeland:  I added a jsfiddle below to show you how I'd do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your divs are set with `position: absolute;`.  This removes the div from the document flow and so the containing element behaves as if the divs are not present for its layout.

I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, but if you want to adjust the position of the two divs, try position relative or examine their margins and padding.  A CSS reset can be very helpful as a general tool for making consistent layouts, especially across browsers.

Here's a jsfiddle of my suggestion, showing the divs side by side and the container behaving as desired.
http://jsfiddle.net/wCnLZ/

Comment: but if they are not `position: absolute; left: 0;` and `right: 0;` then they do not float side by side.

Comment: Sorry, that's how absolute positioning works.  In most cases, I avoid it because it has very limited uses.  Try using the `float` rule instead.  After your floated divs, use a "clear" div like this: `<div style="clear:both;"></div>`.  This will let you position the divs as you need and the container  will scale with its contents.